# Control Custom logging in Application Insight TelemetryClient

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I used `TelemetryClient` to sink my application logs in Application Insight. Now I want to control my logging according to the environment.

I tried to set [LogLevel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#configure-categories-and-log-levels) using host.json file but it's not working. I don't see any property in `TelemetryClient` to pass LogLeve from AppSettings.

```
public class Log : ILog
{
    private static TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient() { InstrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"] };

    public void Error(string message, Exception ex = null)
    {
        telemetryClient.TrackTrace(message, SeverityLevel.Error);
        if (ex != null)
            telemetryClient.TrackException(ex);
    }

    public void Info(string message)
    {
        telemetryClient.TrackTrace(message, SeverityLevel.Information);
    }

    public void Verbose(string message)
    {
        telemetryClient.TrackTrace(message, SeverityLevel.Verbose);
    }

    public void Warning(string message)
    {
        telemetryClient.TrackTrace(message, SeverityLevel.Warning);
    }
}
```

**host.json**

```
{  "logger": {    "categoryFilter": {      "defaultLevel": "Information"     }}
```

**Function**

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req,
        ExecutionContext context, [Inject] ILog log)
    {
        log.Verbose("verbose log");
        log.Info("info log");
        log.Error("error log");
        log.Warning("warning log");
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Okay");
    }
```

**ApplicationInsight**

I don't want verbose log in Prod env.

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide a sample code of the ILog? then I can try to find a solution following your code.

Comment: nothing special in Interface. all public method of Log class only